# How to make composite User Control VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding

```
<Serializable()>    
Public Class PersonNameOnly
   
    Private p_Name As String = ""
    Public Sub New()
        ' needed for deserialization
    End Sub

    Public Property Name As String
        Get
            Return p_Name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            p_Name = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

[WinForm]

The `PersonNameOnly` Class above is bonded Type of BindingSource on the `PersonUsercontrolForPersonWithNameOnly` user control, the name is bonded to a `Textbox`.

`MainUsercontrolForPersonWithNameOnly` has a collection of the `PersonUsercontrolForPersonWithNameOnly`

All the Above Works Fine in the Existing app.

I need new to create a new Form `MainUsercontrolForPersonWITHIMAGE` So I have created a new `UserControl` that inherits `PersonUsercontrolForPersonWithNameOnly`  and added a `Label` that holds the ImageUrl, so This is what I've done so far below.

```
<Serializable()>
Public Class PersonWITHIMAGE
    Inherits PersonNameOnly
    Private p_ImageUrl As String = ""
    Public Sub New()
        ' needed for deserialization
    End Sub

    Public Property ImageUrl As String
        Get
            Return p_ImageUrl
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            p_ImageUrl = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

[WinForm]

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()>
Partial Class PersonUsercontrolForPersonWITHIMAGE 
    Inherits PersonUsercontrolForPersonWithNameOnly
```

How Can I Merge the two data binding as if it was one source, I manage to get the Name only to work on the top-level form with the collection but am not sure how to merge the data in sync with the name only User Control.

How Can I merge the two data binding in once composite form?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be wanting to bind to two different types, of which one is a base type of the other. I don't think you can do that.

But have you looked at using an interface, eg `IPersonUsercontrolForPerson` and basing each class on it? This should open up the possibility of abstracting your control binding.

**Disclaimer!** This answer should act as a jumping-off point as I haven't actually coded up a test/answer for you. But that's where I'd start looking.

Comment: Thanks, have you got any links to examples or samples, please?

Comment: I did miss out a key detail that the classes were <Serializable()> for XML so I had some issues with Interfaces for that's why I was looking for alternate solution